# Return a Subclass in a getter Method without knowing the subclass

Tags: java

I have an abstract class `Item` class whose subclasses are `Weapon` `Shield` and `Potion`.

```
abstract public class Character {

    private Item item;

    public Character(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }
}

public class Hero extends Character{

    public Hero(Item item) {
        super(item);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hero h = new Hero(new Weapon("sword"));
        System.out.println(h.getItem().getDamage());
        /* getDamage is not known because it is not a method of the Item
           class, it is a method of the Weapon class */

        Hero h1 = new Hero(new Potion("syrup"));
        System.out.println(h1.getItem().getPower());
        /* again getPower() is not known */
    }
}
```

What can I do so that `this.item` is returned as a `Weapon/Potion...` and not as an `Item`. I have done research and figure I need to change the method `public Item getItem()` to the method `public <T extends Item> getItem()` or cast `this.item` as a `Weapon/Potion/Shield` but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: If someone hands you a `Hero`, you _don't know_ what kind of `Item` they have.  Casting or generics aren't going to help if you can't first figure out what kind of item it is, because you'll cast _wrong._

Comment: It will be far easier to have three variables for Weapon, Shield and Potion.  Then you can have methods like getWeapon() instead of the more difficult to manage getItem()

Comment: To know the Item subclass and use its methods, you can use the type parameter as suggested by marsouf. I'd suggest, however, that you look for a way to not care what type of Item you have. Each subclass of Item overrides methods from Item to do exactly what you need. So a "use" method could inflict damage if it's a Weapon, recover health if it's a Potion, and reduce damage if it's a shield. The signature may actually be something like use(Character useBy, Character useOn) and you could put a useItemOn(Character useOn) method on the Character class that then calls Item's use method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstract class Character
{
    private Item item;

    public Character (Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public <T extends Item> T getItem (Class <? extends T> targetType)
    {
        return targetType.cast(this.item);
    }

    public void setItem (Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class Hero extends Character
{
    public Hero (Item item)
    {
        super (item);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hero hero1 = new Hero(new Weapon("sword"));
        Weapon weapon = hero1.getItem(Weapon.class);
        hero1.setItem(new Potion("syrup"));
        Potion potion = hero1.getItem(Potion.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea. However, suppose I wanted to change the item to a Potion after instantiating the hero object. Would i just create a setter method such a`public void setItem(T new_item) { this.item = new_time }`

Comment: Everything compiles but can you explain the `getItem` method in detail. I am not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: in the getItem metthod, you specify a type as a parameter that the attribute item will be casted to. so if you specify Potion.class which is equivalent to Class<Potion>, the attribute will be casted to Potion and the method will return a type of Potion. but be careful, you can set an item of type Weapon and if you cast it to for example Potion, you will get an exception.

Comment: Also thank you. Your answer addressed my question perfectly and precisely. Seriously the exact thing i was trying to accomplish/figure out you accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I should use "casting" like these:

```
if (this.item instanceof Weapon)
{
   ((Weapon) this.item).fire() ;
}
else if (this.item instanceof Potion)
{
   ((Potion) this.item).drink() ;
}
else // Shield
{
   ((Shield) this.item).defend() ;
}
```