# Avoid using multiple if-else statements

Tags: java, generics

`Item` is an abstract class with subclasses `Potion, Weapon. Shield`.

The `useItem()` method is an abstract method defined in each of `Item's` subclasses

`get_item` return object of class `Item`

The `getItem` method returns an object of class subclass of `Item`

```
case "use":
    if (hero.get_item() instanceof Potion) {
        hero.<Potion>getItem(Potion.class).useItem();

    } else if (hero.get_item() instanceof Weapon) {
        hero.<Weapon>getItem(Weapon.class).useItem();

    } else if (hero.get_item() instanceof Shield) {
        hero.<Shield>getItem(Shield.class).useItem();
    }
    break;
```

is there a way I can condense this code into something like...

```
Class itemclass = hero.getItem().getClass();
hero.<itemclass>getItem(itemclass.class).useItem();
```

The code above does not compile but I am looking for something like it. I am trying to avoid `if else` statements because there are many more items.

**Edit:**

The reason i did not initially use `hero.get_item().useItem()` was because 
i was trying to do

```
Weapon sword = hero.get_item();
```

so i could access methods such as `sword.getDamage()`

However, I would get the error `error: incompatible types: Item cannot be converted to a Weapon`

so that is why I created (help from @marsouf) `hero.<Weapon>getItem(Weapon.class)`

Today i created the method `abstract public void useItem();`
and since it is a method of the `Item` class I am able to use `hero.getItem().useItem()`

Comment: If `useItem()` is defined on `Item`, which is what `get_item()` is returning, why not just `hero.get_item().useItem()`?

Comment: since all the classes seem to implement the useItem() method you should be able to simply do hero.get_item().useItem();

Comment: that does not work. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466740/return-a-subclass-in-a-getter-method-without-knowing-the-subclass/45467766?noredirect=1#comment77900579_45467766]

Comment: @kevinLloyd In your case, you don't need to know the subclass. The correct implementation of `useItem`  will be called by the runtime even if the declared type is just `Item`

Comment: actually I will try that. I hadn't created the use item function yesterday so I had to create that really strange function

Comment: ["Replace Conditional with Polymorphism"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922788/what-is-replace-conditional-with-polymorphism-refactoring-how-is-it-implemented)

Comment: Could you show your `Item` class (or interface)?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to haven an `Interface` for `Item` with the method `useItem()`.

Then have an implementation for `Potion`, `Shield` etc.

This way you avoid having to cast and make it more complex than it is.

`useItem()` does not belong in the abstract class if its not giving any functionality, and less needed now Interfaces can have `default` methods.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use the magic of generics without not cast

```
public class Character<T extends Item> {
    private T item;

    public Character (T item){
        this.item = item;
    }

    public T getItem(){
       return item;
    }
}
```

When you create a hero:

```
Character hero = new Character<Weapon>(new Weapon("sword"));
```

after this you can use it like:

```
hero.getItem().useItem(); // abstract method from Item class
hero.getItem().getPower(); //where power is a Weapon method
```

Character class you can extend like:

```
public class Hero<T> extend Character<T>{
  //add there your custom methods or override Character methods
}
```

Comment: With your idea is it possible to change the item the hero has with a setter method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466740/return-a-subclass-in-a-getter-method-without-knowing-the-subclass I went with marsouf's answer

Comment: You can change item only to be of same type, for my example, the hero can have only another Weapon but can not has an Potion. If you want to can change Weapon with setter but to have different methods, move the logic of using item to Item class/subcalss or to one delagate

Comment: @kevinLloyd then you should accept marsouf's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without seeing the contracts being involved (hero.get_item(), hero.getItem()).

But have you tried:

```
Class<?> itemClass = hero.get_item().getClass();
hero.getItem(itemClass).useIt();
```

?

Comment: that does not work. It gives illegal start of type error

Comment: can you update your question, adding the signatures for get_item() and getItem() ? otherwise we're just guessing what your api is about.

Comment: i had a typo on the itemClass declaration, try it now. but will be much easier if you just provide the signatures of your hero methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are set on using generics the way you're using them... here's how.

First, I've created some extremely simple classes to mimic your structure from this and your other question: a class which uses instances of a particular abstract class.

```
public class ACOne extends AbstractClass
{
    @Override
    public void use(){System.out.println("Used item ACOne!");}
}
public class ACTwo extends AbstractClass
{
    @Override
    public void use(){System.out.println("Used item ACTwo!");}
}
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void use();
}
public class UserClass
{
    private AbstractClass item;
    public UserClass (AbstractClass item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public Class<? extends AbstractClass> getItemClass()
    {
        return item.getClass();
    }
    public <T extends AbstractClass> T getItem (Class <? extends T> targetType)
    {
        return targetType.cast(this.item);
    }
    public void setItem (AbstractClass item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
public class CastingSubclasses
{
    public void testCastingSubclasses()
    {
        UserClass user = new UserClass(new ACOne());
        user.setItem(new ACTwo());
        user.getItem(user.getItemClass()).use();
    }
}
```

This program, when run, prints out "Used item ACTwo!"

The crux here is in the getItemClass method on the UserClass (your Character class).
Also, it's common to call these methods which get the Class object 'getClazz', since there is a default method 'getClass' that you don't want to override.
Here it made sense to just keep the spelling.